# SQL DB2 store query result into variable

Tags: sql

Usind a DB2 tables:
This is what is done manually in a table

```
select app_id from table_app where APP_NAME='App_Temp';
```

gets me an ID, say it's 234

I copy than and do:

```
select * form table_roles where role_app_id=234;
```

gets me a row , which is my desired end result.

Is there a way save the result of the first one into a variable and do the second query without the manual step in between using local variables?

I know, you can query out the information with a very simple join between two tables, but I'd like to know, how it works with variables. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Just can just plug it in:

```
select *
from table_roles
where role_app_id = (select app_id from table_app where APP_NAME = 'App_Temp');
```

If there can be more than one match, use `in` instead of `=`.

You can also phrase this as a join:

```
select r.*
from table_roles r join
     table_app
     on r.role_app_id = a.app_id and APP_NAME = 'App_Temp';
```

However, this might return duplicates, if two apps have the same name.  In that case, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct r.*
from table_roles r join
     table_app
     on r.role_app_id = a.app_id and APP_NAME = 'App_Temp';
```

Comment: As I already said, I know, how I can do it very easily with joins (or an in). But I want to know how things work with local variables. So this is really just a very easy example I want transferred into a version using variables. The example could have been pretty much anything else, it was jsut the first thing I thought up.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same kind of issue here's what I’ve done:
I’ve created a PL/SQL block where I can save the result of the select query with the INTO keyword:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE res INTEGER;
    select app_id INTO res from table_app where APP_NAME='App_Temp';

    -- 'app_id' is saved in the 'res' variable
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).